# Continuous Speech to text in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, transcription

I was trying to create an app, that can transcribe from speech to text, but the problem is , that it is not continuous.
I'm using a dependency called speech_to_text - https://pub.dev/packages/speech_to_text . In the troubleshooting section of the dependency, it is stated that "Currently the plugin is designed for short intermittent use, like when expecting a response to a question, or issuing a single voice command. "

Here is the original code -

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:highlight_text/highlight_text.dart';
import 'package:speech_to_text/speech_to_text.dart' as stt;
import 'package:clipboard/clipboard.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';
import 'package:iconsax/iconsax.dart';
import 'package:voicerra/Screens/about_page.dart';
import 'package:voicerra/Screens/voice_beta.dart';

class VoiceApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const VoiceApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Voicerra',
      theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          elevatedButtonTheme: ElevatedButtonThemeData(
              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  elevation: 12,
                  minimumSize: const Size.square(52),
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                  )))),
      home: const SpeechScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class SpeechScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SpeechScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<SpeechScreen> createState() => _SpeechScreenState();
}

class _SpeechScreenState extends State<SpeechScreen> {
  final Map<String, HighlightedWord> _highlights = {
    'project': HighlightedWord(
      textStyle: const TextStyle(
          color: Colors.blue,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          fontFamily: 'Raleway',
          fontSize: 24.0),
    ),
    'exhibition': HighlightedWord(
      textStyle: const TextStyle(
          color: Colors.green,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          fontFamily: 'Raleway',
          fontSize: 24.0),
    ),
    'group': HighlightedWord(
      textStyle: const TextStyle(
          color: Colors.red,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          fontFamily: 'Raleway',
          fontSize: 24.0),
    ),
  };

  late stt.SpeechToText _speech;
  bool _isListening = false;
  String _text = 'Voicerra!';
  double _confidence = 1.0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _speech = stt.SpeechToText();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF2f2554),
        appBar: AppBar(
          toolbarHeight: 80,
          backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF2f2554),
          elevation: 0,
          centerTitle: true,
          title: Text(
              'Confidence: ${(_confidence * 100.0).toStringAsFixed(1)}%',
              style: const TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Raleway', fontSize: 24.0)),
          actions: [
            PopupMenuButton(
              shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                  Radius.circular(20.0),
                ),
              ),
              onSelected: (value) {
                switch (value) {
                  case 'About us':
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => const AboutPage()),
                    );
                    break;
                  case 'Try (Beta)':
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => const BetaVoice()),
                    );
                    break;
                }
              },
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
                return ['About us', 'Try (Beta)'].map((String choice) {
                  return PopupMenuItem(
                    value: choice,
                    child: Center(
                        child: Text(
                      choice,
                      style: const TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Raleway'),
                    )),
                  );
                }).toList();
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
        floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
        floatingActionButton: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
            children: [
              ElevatedButton(
                style: ButtonStyle(
                    backgroundColor:
                        MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.blue.shade100),
                    foregroundColor:
                        MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.black),
                    overlayColor: getColor(
                      const Color(0xFFf6edfd),
                      const Color(0xFF2f2554),
                    )),
                onPressed: _listen,
                child: Icon(_isListening ? Icons.mic : Icons.mic_off),
              ),
              Expanded(child: Container()),
              FloatingActionButton(
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                ),
                backgroundColor: Colors.blue.shade100,
                foregroundColor: Colors.black,
                onPressed: () async {
                  await FlutterClipboard.copy(_text);
                  Fluttertoast.showToast(
                    msg: "✓   Copied to Clipboard",
                    toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
                  );
                },
                child: const Icon(Iconsax.copy),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(
              parent: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics()),
          child: Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              color: Color(0xFFf2f2f2),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topRight: Radius.circular(50),
                topLeft: Radius.circular(50),
              ),
            ),
            child: Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30.0, 30.0, 30.0, 150.0),
              child: TextHighlight(
                text: _text,
                words: _highlights,
                textStyle: const TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: 'Raleway',
                  fontSize: 24.0,
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }

  void _listen() async {
    if (!_isListening) {
      bool available = await _speech.initialize(
        // ignore: avoid_print
        onStatus: (val) => print('onStatus: $val'),
        // ignore: avoid_print
        onError: (val) => print('onError: $val'),
      );
      if (available) {
        setState(() => _isListening = true);
        _speech.listen(
          onResult: (val) => setState(() {
            _text = val.recognizedWords;
            if (val.hasConfidenceRating && val.confidence > 0) {
              _confidence = val.confidence;
            }
          }),
        );
      }
    } else {
      setState(() => _isListening = false);
      _speech.stop();
    }
  }

  getColor(Color color, Color colorPressed) {
    getColor(Set<MaterialState> states) {
      if (states.contains(MaterialState.pressed)) {
        return colorPressed;
      } else {
        return color;
      }
    }

    return MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith(getColor);
  }
}
```

I am able to achieve Continuous transcription by a workaround (Manually stopping the active speech recognition session and restarting it) but it's too inefficient, and doesn't work half of the time

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:speech_to_text/speech_recognition_error.dart';
import 'package:speech_to_text/speech_recognition_result.dart';
import 'package:speech_to_text/speech_to_text.dart';

class BetaVoice extends StatefulWidget {
  const BetaVoice({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<BetaVoice> createState() => _BetaVoiceState();
}

class _BetaVoiceState extends State<BetaVoice> {
  final SpeechToText _speechToText = SpeechToText();
  bool _speechEnabled = false;
  bool _speechAvailable = false;
  String _lastWords = '';
  String _currentWords = '';

  printLocales() async {
    var locales = await _speechToText.locales();
    for (var local in locales) {
      debugPrint(local.name);
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _initSpeech();
  }

  void errorListener(SpeechRecognitionError error) {
    debugPrint(error.errorMsg.toString());
  }

  void statusListener(String status) async {
    debugPrint("status $status");
    if (status == "done" && _speechEnabled) {
      setState(() {
        _lastWords += " $_currentWords";
        _currentWords = "";
        _speechEnabled = false;
      });
      await _startListening();
    }
  }

  /// This has to happen only once per app
  void _initSpeech() async {
    _speechAvailable = await _speechToText.initialize(
        onError: errorListener, onStatus: statusListener);
    setState(() {});
  }

  /// Each time to start a speech recognition session
  Future _startListening() async {
    await _stopListening();
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 50));
    await _speechToText.listen(
        onResult: _onSpeechResult,
        cancelOnError: true,
        partialResults: true,
        listenMode: ListenMode.dictation);
    setState(() {
      _speechEnabled = true;
    });
  }

  /// Manually stop the active speech recognition session
  /// Note that there are also timeouts that each platform enforces
  /// and the SpeechToText plugin supports setting timeouts on the
  /// listen method.
  Future _stopListening() async {
    setState(() {
      _speechEnabled = false;
    });
    await _speechToText.stop();
  }

  /// This is the callback that the SpeechToText plugin calls when
  /// the platform returns recognized words.
  void _onSpeechResult(SpeechRecognitionResult result) {
    setState(() {
      _currentWords = result.recognizedWords;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF2f2554),
      appBar: AppBar(
        toolbarHeight: 80,
        backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF2f2554),
        elevation: 0,
        centerTitle: true,
        title: const Text('Transcription (Beta)',
            style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Raleway', fontSize: 24.0)),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(
            parent: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics()),
        child: Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topRight: Radius.circular(50),
              topLeft: Radius.circular(50),
            ),
          ),
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16.0, 30.0, 16.0, 10),
                  child: const Text(
                    '*Note: This is a highly experimental feature*',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: 'Raleway',
                        fontSize: 20.0,
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                    child: Text(
                      _lastWords.isNotEmpty
                          ? '$_lastWords $_currentWords'
                          : _speechAvailable
                              ? 'Voicerra !'
                              : 'Speech not available',
                      style: const TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: 'Raleway',
                        fontSize: 24.0,
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue.shade100,
        foregroundColor: Colors.black,
        onPressed:
            _speechToText.isNotListening ? _startListening : _stopListening,
        tooltip: 'Tap to start Transcribing',
        child: Icon(_speechToText.isNotListening ? Icons.mic_off : Icons.mic),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have also looked at 3rd party online transcription sites like deepgram and gcloud for api that uses  sound stream package for live conversion but its too expensive for public use.

I therefore want a permanent solution to implement continuous speech to text recognition, be it with or without the dependency , either by calling native kotlin/java code or any means to open the microphone permission on continuously. If you could please help me out :) .

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: You can use the speech_to_text package to convert speech to text in Flutter.I also added permission_handler package to request microphone permission and check its status.
Step 2: Add the required permission to  /android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml for android.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT"/>
<queries>
  <intent>
    <action android:name="android.speech.RecognitionService" />
  </intent>
</queries>
```

Run the following code on the main page.
Here I have designed a simple looking screen for you that includes a microphone button and when you turn on the microphone and start speaking, your speech will be converted into text and displayed in the text widget.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
import 'package:speech_to_text/speech_recognition_result.dart';
import 'package:speech_to_text/speech_to_text.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const SpeechScreen(title: 'Speech',),
    );
  }
}

class SpeechScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SpeechScreen({super.key, required this.title});
  final String title;

  @override
  State<SpeechScreen> createState() => _SpeechScreenState();
}

class _SpeechScreenState extends State<SpeechScreen> {
  final SpeechToText _speechToText = SpeechToText();
  bool _speechEnabled = false;
  String _lastWords = "";

  void listenForPermissions() async {
  final status = await Permission.microphone.status;
  switch (status) {
    case PermissionStatus.denied:
      requestForPermission();
      break;
    case PermissionStatus.granted:
      break;
    case PermissionStatus.limited:
      break;
    case PermissionStatus.permanentlyDenied:
      break;
    case PermissionStatus.restricted:
      break;
    case PermissionStatus.provisional:
      // TODO: Handle this case.
  }
}

Future<void> requestForPermission() async {
  await Permission.microphone.request();
}

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  listenForPermissions();
  if (!_speechEnabled) {
    _initSpeech();
  }
}

void _initSpeech() async {
  _speechEnabled = await _speechToText.initialize();
}

void _startListening() async {
  await _speechToText.listen(
    onResult: _onSpeechResult,
    listenFor: const Duration(seconds: 30),
    localeId: "en_En",
    cancelOnError: false,
    partialResults: false,
    listenMode: ListenMode.confirmation,
  );
  setState(() {});
}

void _stopListening() async {
  await _speechToText.stop();
  setState(() {});
}

void _onSpeechResult(SpeechRecognitionResult result) {
  setState(() {
    _lastWords = "${result.recognizedWords} ";
  });
}


@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
    ),
    floatingActionButtonLocation: 
      FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
    floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: _speechToText.isNotListening
        ? _startListening
        : _stopListening,
      child: Icon(_speechToText.isNotListening
        ? Icons.mic_off
        : Icons.mic
      ),
    ),
    body: Center(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(25),
            child: Text(_speechToText.isListening
              ? "Listening..."
              : _speechEnabled
                ? "Tap the microphone to start listening.."
                : "Speech not available"
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(25),
              child: Text(_lastWords),
            )
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}}
```

Comment: it still listens for 3-4 seconds only.